# Outlook Rendering Cursive Font in Sender

Tags: fonts, outlook

This is a new one for me. I'm seeing a cursive font in the Sender line of an email in Outlook web. I'm seeing it in slightly different cursive fonts between browsers (I've checked Chrome, FF, and Safari), but they're pretty close. The really strange thing to me is that the cursive font is also rendering in the DOM tree in DevTools.

The Computed Styles tab is showing a rendered font of Cambria Math, but that doesn't jive with what I'm seeing.

Here are a couple of screenshots of what I'm seeing in Chrome:

Inbox view:
[image: Chrome inbox view]

DevTools View:
[image: DevTools view]

Does anyone have some insight into how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clue is in what you're seeing in the DOM tree in your dev tools, I would say; notice that the *text* in that DOM node is itself in cursive. That's not what the DOM shows if this was a font applied to plain text. Rather than `Credit One [...]` in the DOM node with the CSS saying some cursive font is being used, we see   `[...]`. It's literally straight up cursive text.

This isn't strictly speaking "a font", it's characters from a part of Unicode where the formal definition of the glyph is a cursive Latin character (in this specific case, the `Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols` block, U+1D4D0 through U+1D503)